# Not an entity:class java.lang.Long in remove method in JPARepository

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, liferay

i have strange behaviour with Liferay server 6.2 + Hibernate.
I have created portlet, which i have deployed on 2 LF servers. This portlet is communicating with the same postgres db. Everything is working, except the remove method.

The error message is only on one LF server.

```
18:21:39,831 ERROR [DispatcherPortlet:559] Could not complete request
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Not an entity:class java.lang.Long; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity:class java.lang.Long
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:296)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:106)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1288.delete(Unknown Source)
```

I have repository

```
@Repository
public interface FavouritesRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<FavouritesRequest, Serializable>{
```

and using this method

```
@Override
    public void remove(Long id) {
         repository.delete(id);

    }
```

and now the POJO class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Favouritesrequests")
@Access(value=AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class FavouritesRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7432660452646512046L;

    private Long id=(long) 0;
    private Request request;

    private Long userId=(long) 0;;
```

with

```
@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="REQID",  nullable=true)
public Request getRequest() {
    return request;
}
```

I have tried to build own query in repository, but no success yet. The error message on the one server remains the same.

Thanx for any help.

Comment: Have you tried with `repository.delete(id.longValue());` in `remove()`

Comment: Yes, but no success, the error is still the same.

Comment: I think you are supposed to pass the entire Entity class to delete, not just it's primary key. So you will need to find it first.

Comment: Thanx, the remove method it is normally working on one LF server, and according to the JPARepository, the id should be enough for it.

Comment: I would define `FavouritesRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<FavouritesRequest, Long>`, as your ID is a `Long`. Additionally it is not a good style to initialize the ID - leaving it `null` makes it easy to check if the entity is persisted. And instead of (long) 0 you can write 0L.

Comment: Hi Tobias, yes, it was the solution. You can write it here as an answer.